# Is it possible to add a condition to a LEFT OUTER JOIN in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

Given this structure:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users
    has_many :teams
    validates :name, presence: true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :account
    has_and_belongs_to_many :teams
    validates :name, presence: true
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :account
    has_and_belongs_to_many :users
    validates :name, presence: true
end
```

The objective is to obtain a list/array of all the team ids/names for an account, along with a flag indicating whether a given user belongs to the team or not.

In SQL I can get this result with something like:

```
SELECT teams.id, teams.name, 
     teams_users.team_id IS NOT NULL AS member FROM teams 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN teams_users ON 
        (teams.id = teams_users.team_id AND team_users.user_id = ?)
    WHERE teams.account_id = ?
```

Is there a Rails 4 / ActiveRecord way to get the same result? Every attempt I've made has pushed the `teams_users.user_id = ?` condition into the WHERE clause, which only returns a list of teams for which the user is a member, rather than all the teams associated with the account.

Comment: were you able to figure this out? I need to also add a and condition to the `on` for the left join

Answer (score 6):

It should be possible with the string form of `joins`. Sanitize any user input before interpolating into the string.

```
Team.select(:id, :name).
  select("teams_users.team_id IS NOT NULL AS member FROM teams").
  joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN teams_users ON (teams.id = teams_users.team_id AND team_users.user_id = #{current_user.id})").
  where(account_id: account.id)
```

Comment: Thanks -that's approx what I'm currently using! I'm really hoping to find a method which doesn't involve the nasty string interpolation in the join...

Comment: I could construct an Arel-ized version if you like. I'm a much bigger fan of the string version, however.

Comment: You can avoid interpolation and use standard query escaping with `?`, like `joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN ... team_users.user_id = ?', current_user.id)`.

Comment: @TTT that form is not supported in `joins`, at least in Rails 5.0 (note the question specified version 4). `Model.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN ... models.user_id.id = ?', 1).to_a =>
NoMethodError: undefined method 'class_name' for 1:Integer`